# How to avoid the sudo word, for executing the higher privilged commands by a non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, sudoers

Is it possible avoid sudo word while executing the higher privileged commands to a non-root user via a sudo policy such non-root users should not be able to know that he is executing higher privileged commands and also the usage of sudo might be complex.

Example: 
Normal Execution of Sudo Command.

```
$ sudo -u root /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

non-root users should execute tcpdump like below.

```
$ tcpdump
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: I have defined a Sudo Policy for non-root users. So, when a non-root user executes tcpdump, in the backend it should execute as 
sudo -u root tcpdump.

Comment: You could define an `alias tcpdump='sudo tcpdump'`.

Comment: Do you mean to add the alias of the non-root user bash profiles?

Comment: Why was this question tagged with `perl`?

Comment: @dgw - Good question.  So I removed the Perl tag.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is possible.

You should:

1- Create a new specific new group where some users would belong:

```
groupadd nonroot
```

2- Add your *privileged* users to that group:

2.1- Edit /etc/group:

```
vim /etc/group
```

2.2- Find the line of new created group. It should look like that:

```
nonroot:x:127:
```

2.3- At the end, add your privilaged users:

```
nonroot:x:127:user1,user2
```

3- Change the group of your binary:

```
chgrp nonroot /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

4- Give group execution permissions to the binary:

```
chmod g+x /usr/bin/tcpdump
```

You have to have in count that if the binary reads, writes or executes files which user1 has no permissions, you'll have modify them in the same way.

If you cannot change the group of the binary, check the right answer of post bellow, which is a similar way:

[Allow users of a certain group to run a command without sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/636726/allow-users-of-a-certain-group-to-run-a-command-without-sudo)

Hope it helps.

NOTE: Commands may differ between different linux/unix distros.

Comment: appreciate for the answer nicof, but this is not what i am looking for.

Comment: @sach - If you told us _why_ this isn't the answer you're looking for, it would greatly improve your chances of getting a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @nicof, i will be defining the sudo policies for few users such that the users will have permission to execute the commands defined in the policy. I need a way to hide the users to type sudo. Thus, i am looking a way where users will just execute the commands without typing sudo usage.

Comment: @sach - I assume when you talk about _sudo policies_ you mean to configure /etc/sudoers file for some users. This file permits to execute some high level binaries to some users or group of them, but always typing _sudo_ before, because sudoers file is a configuration for that file.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, you can't omit using _sudo_ from "/etc/sudoers"  configuration
If you read the link I posted at the end, you have an option that consist in creating a script to _hide_ the sudo utilization (as Henrik said in his answer)

Answer (score 0):

I can see at least two possibilities:

1. Wrap it in a script (an alias is also possible, but if users can use different shells or just start them manually, it can turn into a maintenence hell)
2. Set the suid bit on tcpdump, but that means everyone who can invoke tcpdump always does so as the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore using sudoers file.

Using CentOS as an example (should be similar for Debian), create a file within sudoers.d with the relevant name, e.g. `tcpdump` and include the following:

`user ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tcpdump command`

Replace the user and command to suit your purpose. You can find out more [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file#how-to-set-up-custom-rules).

This coupled with a alias `tcpdump='sudo tcpdump` for the user should fit your use case.